# Change range of a DC signal without changing the offset with op amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-design, signal-processing, signal-theory

I have a voltage signal with the following range:

low - 2.5VDC
middle point - 2.725VDC
high - 2.95VDC

I would like to condition this signal to:

low - 0.4VDC
middle point - 1.65VDC
high - 2.9VDC

I have only a +/-12VDC power supply available, op-amps, capacitors and resistors. Anybody has any suggestions on how can I do it? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Added by DKNguyen for clarification.[image]

Comment: You need a voltage reference; the less accurate it is, the less accurate your result will be.  Do you have anything that you could use?

Comment: I have a 12VDC power supply and could build a voltage divider with some resistors

Comment: You need to offset it to 1.65V, then amplify it about 1.65V which means you might need a negative supply.

Comment: I need to have 1.65V as my midpoint. I am planning to use the op. amp TL074IN

Comment: Yes, it is linear

Comment: I misread the post.  Gonna delete some misleading comments, leaving _other_ comments out of context.  Oops!

Comment: If I offset it to 1.65V though, when I amplify the signal, since it is only DC, it will amplify the midpoint to, and I'd like to increase only the range of the signal, but keeping 1.65VDC as my midpoint

Comment: @CharlesWagner You just choose a different midpoint. An opamp amplifier doesn't *need* to amplify relative to ground. It's just the sample circuits you see online often do because there's no real application behind them or specific signal re-scaling that they need to achieve.

Comment: @CharlesWagner What's the source impedance? I suppose, if you expect the circuit to have "very high" input impedance, it may not matter. But knowing the source impedance still may help in considering (and removing) alternative ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code imported into [Falstad Circuit Simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html)

```
 $ 1 0.000005 10.20027730826997 57 5 50 5e-11
v -176 224 -176 176 0 0 40 2.5 0 0 0.5
w 304 304 304 352 0
a 304 288 448 288 9 15 -15 1000000 1.4249675011270142 1.4249715005717007 100000
w 448 288 448 352 0
r 304 352 448 352 0 45550
r 208 352 304 352 0 10000
w 208 208 304 208 0
w 304 208 304 272 0
O 448 288 512 288 0 0
a 64 208 208 208 9 15 -15 1000000 0.7124857502849943 0.7125 100000
v -80 320 -80 272 0 0 40 -1.075 0 0 0.5
r 0 160 -80 160 0 50000
r 0 224 -80 224 0 50000
w -80 160 -128 160 0
g -80 320 -80 336 0 0
r 64 272 208 272 0 10000
w 208 272 208 208 0
w 64 224 64 272 0
w 0 224 64 192 0
w 64 192 0 160 0
g -176 224 -176 240 0 0
r 64 272 64 336 0 10000
g 64 336 64 352 0 0
v 208 400 208 352 0 0 40 1.65 0 0 0.5
g 208 400 208 416 0 0
x -241 102 -210 105 4 15 Input
x -163 304 -113 307 4 15 -1.075V
x 149 379 186 382 4 15 1.65V
x -67 109 -4 112 4 24 Offset
x 42 107 367 110 4 24 Offset\sCompensation\sAmplifier
x 329 222 599 225 4 24 Dynamic\sRange\sAmplifier
w -80 224 -80 272 0
S -128 160 -176 160 0 0 false 0 2
S -176 144 -224 144 0 0 false 0 2
v -224 208 -224 160 0 0 40 2.725 0 0 0.5
v -272 176 -272 128 0 0 40 2.95 0 0 0.5
g -272 176 -272 192 0 0
g -224 208 -224 224 0 0
w -272 128 -224 128 0
```

Not very elegant, but I'm not sure if op-amp offsetting circuits ever are.

The structure is a summer to offset the voltage center by -1.075V so 2.725V becomes 1.65V. The resistor divider nature of the summer halves the output voltage from what it should be so I re-amplified it by two relative to GND to compensate.

Then the re-centered signal is fed and amplified by a gain of 5.555 to change the dynamic range from \$2.95V-2.5V=0.4V\$ to \$2.9V - 0.4V = 2.5V\$. The amplification here takes place about 1.65V (rather than GND) so that the signal center is preserved.

[image]

Comment: OP, my answer might be easier to understand since each mathematical step has its own circuit block, but Tim Wescott's answer is obviously much more efficient since everything is rolled into a ball.

Comment: You should pick the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want a non-inverting amplifier configuration, with an offset.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foCfWV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Because it's an op-amp, if the circuit is stable then \$V_- = V_{in}\$.  You can calculate \$V_-\$ using the voltage divider equation:

$$V_{in} = V_- = \frac{R_1 V_{out} + R_2 V_1}{R_1 + R_2}.$$

Solving, \$ V_{out} = \left(1 + \frac{R2}{R1}\right) V_{in} - \frac{R2}{R1} V_1\$.

Take two pairs of your voltages:

$$\begin{aligned}
2.9 \mathrm V & = \left(1 + \frac{R2}{R1}\right) 2.95 \mathrm V - \frac{R2}{R1} V_1 \\
0.4 \mathrm V & = \left(1 + \frac{R2}{R1}\right) 2.50 \mathrm V - \frac{R2}{R1} V_1
\end{aligned}$$

Now it's down to high-school algebra (I'll cheat and use Maxima):

$$\frac{R2}{R1} = \frac{41}{9} \simeq 4.56,\ V_1 = \frac{607}{205} \simeq 2.96 \mathrm V.$$

Use a resistive divider to obtain your 2.96V, compute it's Thevenin equivalent resistance (which will just be the parallel equivalent of the two resistors in the divider) then compute R2.  You won't get things exactly right, so then you'll want to juggle resistor values until you get close enough to make you happy (I suggest using math or a circuit simulator to home in on the best values).

[Falstad Circuit Simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/)

```
$ 1 0.000005 10.20027730826997 57 5 50 5e-11
v 80 224 80 176 0 0 40 2.95 0 0 0.5
w 304 304 304 352 0
a 304 288 448 288 9 15 -15 1000000 2.9499709571690462 2.95 100000
w 448 288 448 352 0
r 304 352 448 352 0 41000
r 208 352 304 352 0 9000
w 208 208 304 208 0
w 304 208 304 272 0
O 448 288 512 288 0 0
g 160 272 160 288 0 0
v 208 400 208 352 0 0 40 2.96 0 0 0.5
g 208 400 208 416 0 0
S 208 208 160 208 0 1 false 0 2
S 160 192 128 192 0 1 false 0 2
v 112 256 112 208 0 0 40 2.725 0 0 0.5
v 160 272 160 224 0 0 40 2.5 0 0 0.5
w 80 176 128 176 0
w 112 208 128 208 0
g 80 224 80 240 0 0
g 112 256 112 272 0 0
o 0 64 3 4098 5 0.00009765625 0 1
```